# Align two elements on top of each other without a container with a width

Tags: html, css

I have two elements that I would like to be aligned in a column-like way. These elements also need to be floated to the right of the page. If I float the container containing these two elements to the right, they automatically align in a row-like way. My immediate thought is to specify a width of the container so that they will be forced to move downward. The issue with this is that the two elements are different widths.

```html
<div style="float: right; width: 100px;">
  <div style="width: 110px; height:50px; background-color: blue;">
    Element 1
  </div>
  <div style="width: 60px; height:50px; background-color: red; 
float:right;">
    Element 2
  </div>
</div>
paragraph text that will not flow into the bottom element because the container's width prevents it. Filler text.....
```

[image: Example of what i'm talking about]

If the bottom element is not as wide as the top element, the width of the container makes it wider. This is an issue because I have other text / elements that I would like flow around these side elements, and it looks weird because of the whitespace created by the different in widths.

If I try something like making the parent absolute, as not to effect the other elements on the page, the children don't either.

How can I create elements that are floated in a container without the width of the container affecting the other elements on the page as well? Thanks, Levi

Comment: Would you be able to post the relevant HTML and attempted CSS? Without that we can only try to guess at your situation, which means the answers are less immediately relevant to your situation, and other visitors to this question in future potentially learn less from the question and its answers.

Comment: At a guess, some combination of `float:right; display:flex; flex-direction:column;` might work. But as David said, you should post the relevant HTML and CSS so that we can see what you're really trying to do.

Comment: Sorry about not posting the html and css. I was going to use the built in example editor thing, but it wouldn't work for me for some reason. I'll add some example code anyway. As for what @RichardDeeming said, this doesn't work. Making something `display:flex` causes its width to be as wide as the widest child element, and this is exactly the problem.

Comment: Can you also add an image to show what arrangement you want the various elements to have? I'm looking at it, currently, trying to work out what's wrong with it. Should the Element 1 and Element 2 be on top of each other, *and* above the `<p>` of text? Should they be next to each other, above the text? Should it be something else entirely?

Comment: I'm fairly certain this is not possible with any form of container. To wrap text the elements themselves need to be individually floated and if floated cannot stack in a column. I'd suggest rethinking your methodology.

Comment: I've added an example of what is going on in the form of an image. @DavidThomas I purposefully didn't make the code example into a code snippet because as I mentioned code snippets aren't working for me at the moment. The image is a better example of what I'm experiencing because I can actually see it.

Comment: Closest I can get and I don' t think it will still do what you want. - https://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/LYOVqWG

Answer (score 0):

One approach is as below, taking advantage of `display: contents` comments in the code itself:

```css
/* basic CSS reset to reduce all elements to the same
   box-sizing, font, margin and padding: */
*,
 ::before,
 ::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font: normal 1rem / 1.5 sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}


/* a wrapping element to allow for some dynamic sizing of the
   contents: */
main {
  /* the width of the <main> element is 80vw (viewport-width units)
     unless that is less than 30em (the minimum size it will be) or
     unless that size exceeds 1000px (at which point it will take
     a width of 1000px maximum): */
  width: clamp(30em, 80vw, 1000px);
  /* a margin of 1em on the top and bottom top-to-bottom languages: */
  margin-block: 1em;
  /* a margin of auto on the inline axis, left (start) and right (end)
     in left-to-right languages, such as English: */
  margin-inline: auto;
}

div.wrapper {
  /* for those browsers that are yet to implement
     logical properties: */
  float: right;
  /* equivalent to "float: right" in left-to-right
     languages, such as English: */
  float: inset-inline-end;
  width: 100px;
  /* effectively removes this element from the
     layout, exposing its contents to the layout
     engine: */
  display: contents;
}

div.wrapper > div {
  /* ensuring that the "display: contents" is
     unset, which takes it back to the default
     display model: */
  display: unset;
  /* for those browsers that are yet to implement
     logical properties: */
  float: right;
  /* as above, equivalent to "float: right" in
     left-to-right languages, such as English: */
  float: inset-inline-end;
  height: 50px;
  /* forces each element to clear the float of its
     siblings: */
  clear: both;
  /* to hide the overflowing text: */
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

.wrapper > div:first-child {
  background-color: blue;
  width: 110px;
}

.wrapper > div:last-child {
  background-color: red;
  width: 60px;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div>
      Element 1
    </div>
    <div>
      Element 2
    </div>
  </div>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Consectetur perferendis corporis itaque, sequi quod commodi explicabo dolore, totam, libero architecto doloremque nisi illo iste quae ea, laboriosam reprehenderit nemo animi! Lorem ipsum dolor
    sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quia reiciendis sapiente blanditiis provident ad ullam consequatur, temporibus ex accusamus est nihil voluptatum totam cupiditate. Ducimus sit deserunt nostrum, dolorem doloremque. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
    consectetur adipisicing elit. Consectetur perferendis corporis itaque, sequi quod commodi explicabo dolore, totam, libero architecto doloremque nisi illo iste quae ea, laboriosam reprehenderit nemo animi! Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing
    elit. Quia reiciendis sapiente blanditiis provident ad ullam consequatur, temporibus ex accusamus est nihil voluptatum totam cupiditate. Ducimus sit deserunt nostrum, dolorem doloremque.</p>
</main>
```

[JS Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/pytjhwg1/2/).

References:

- [CSS logical properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Logical_Properties).
- [`display`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display).
- [`float`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/float).

Bibliography:

- [Compatibility of CSS logical properties](https://caniuse.com/css-logical-props), from "Can I Use."

Comment: `float: inline-end;` Doesn't seem to work. You say in the comments that is "equivalent to 'float: right'" but opening devtools in chrome states that `inline-end` is an invalid property value.

Comment: @Levi_OP, my apologies; I used the wrong property; `inline-end` should have been [`inset-inline-end`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/inset-inline-end); I've updated the demo (and the [JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/pytjhwg1/2/) to reflect that update) to use the correct value, and also supply a simple `float: right` for those browsers that have yet to implement logical properties. It's not exactly equivalent, but does at least work for left-to-right languages.